# Pipe tail output into column

Tags: bash, unix, tail

I'm trying to tail a log file and format the output into columns. This gives me what I want without tail:

```
cat /var/log/test.log | column -t -s "|"
```

How can I pipe the output of `tail -f var/log/test.log` into `column`?

EDIT: Here's an excerpt from the file. I'm manually adding the first line of the file so it could be used as the column headers, but I could format it differently if necessary.

```
timestamp|type|uri|referer|user_id|link|message
Feb  5 23:58:29 181d5d6339bd drupal_overlake: 1612569509|geocoder|https://overlake.lando/admin/config/development/configuration/config-split/add|https://overlake.lando/admin/config/development/configuration/config-split/add|0||Could not execute query "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=L-054%2C%20US&language=&region=US".
Feb  5 23:58:29 181d5d6339bd drupal_overlake: 1612569509|geocoder|https://overlake.lando/admin/config/development/configuration/config-split/add|https://overlake.lando/admin/config/development/configuration/config-split/add|0||Unable to geocode 'L-054, US'.
```

Comment: `column` waits until stdin is closed and **then** calculates the number of columns and its width.

Comment: Add an excerpt from your log file and the desired output to your question (no comment).

Comment: Rather than `column`, you might be okay with `tail -f /p/a/t/h |  tr -s ' ' \\t`.  The output is not quite as pretty as `column`, but `tr` can work on a stream. (or, in this case, `tr \| \\t`

Comment: Thank you for your help. @Cyrus, I added an except of the log file. My desired output would be the first line is used as column headers that remain visible at the top of the tail, however I realize this is probably extremely difficult or maybe impossible.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you! I found that modifying the divider in your command is definitely an improvement over `tail` without any piping: `tail -f /var/log/drupal.log | tr -s '|' \\t`  The logs are much more legible.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the `-f` option to `tail`. `column` can't produce any output until it receives all its input, since it needs to calculate the number of rows and columns by examining all the input. `tail -f` never stops writing, so `column` doesn't know when it's done.

You can use

```
tail -n 100 test.log | column -t -s "|"
```

to format the last 100 lines of the log.

Answer (score 0):

##### Actually, there is a way!

Yes, `column` need all final input to process text... but we can trick it: `tail -f` is just "regular `tail` run continuously, right? ツ

```bash
watch -n 1 "tail -n 20 myfile.log | column -t"
```

If you need to keep the first line (as header for instance), you can also do it cleverly:

```bash
watch -n 1 "(head -n1 && tail -n20) < users.csv | column -s, -t"
```

---

**Source:**
https://avilpage.com/2023/01/pipe-tail-output-into-column.html (from SO' user Chillar Anand)